# Trying to Query a list against another list

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

First time ever using stack exchange so please excuse any formatting problems.

I'm trying to create a sheet where Sheet1 is a dump of data and Sheet2 contains:

- A date range
- A list of items
- True/False checkboxes for each item

I pretty much immediately wrote off the checkboxes as helper cells and created a hidden query to dump everything that was marked true in what I'm going to call Range_Items (Though I'm really just referencing the cells they were dumped in).

I haven't tried limiting the final query against the date range yet, because I'm having trouble making it pull from Sheet1 against the Range_Items list. So I tried paring it down to a simpler formula for concept and still can't seem to figure out why it won't pull anything. This is the simplest iteration I can think of:

```
=Query('Transaction Dump'!$A:$J,"select B,C,E,F,G,I where C = 'Expense'")
```

But when I try `C = Or('Expense', 'Transfer')` using cell reference or lack of single quotes, I get hit with errors.

I'm sure the problem is the syntax, but I really can't tell what's stopping it.

Some other attempts I've tried include:

- Simply referencing the cell range in the OR function
- Nesting another query into the query
- `=TEXTJOIN(",C =",True,$O$41:$O$57)` where I then prefix that statement with `=arrayformula("C = " & $C$59)` since the first list item would not have the C = operator and stick that into the Query's Or function.

I've tried a billion combinations of single, double, and & insertions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try it like this and if you will need in future the **`and`** you just replace the **`or`**:


  ```
  =QUERY('Transaction Dump'!$A:$J, 
   "select B,C,E,F,G,I 
    where C = 'Expense'
       or C = 'Transfer'", 0)
  ```
- also you may change **`=`** to **`matches`** or **`contains`**

### _______________________________________________________________

cell **B59**:

```
="contains '"&TEXTJOIN("' or Col3 contains '", 1, $O$41:$O$57)&"'"
```

cell **Y3**:

```
=QUERY({'Transaction Dump'!$A7:$J}, 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col9 where Col3 "&C59, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Changing `=` to `matches` and swapping `and` for `or` seems to be doing the trick for manual insertion. But I'm still trying to reach the goal of it pulling it from that Range_List of items as I'll be checking them on or off whether I need that data at the moment. I thought if I populated a cell with a string of `C matches ___` then I could just insert that cell reference into the query, but that doesn't seem to work. Also, I may not know the proper way to reference a cell in a Query function. I'm inserting it `'C60'`.

Comment: that won't do coz `QUERY` is not able to work with arrays/ranges mentioned as comparison params

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative? I was tooling around with the `filter` function, but that doesn't seem to be working as intended either. Seems like it needs a very finite range, because attempting an entire column gives me a "mismatched range" error.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure, here's a link of a copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rjfMChHBNu8oeK5azMj8_yywgXa0-_JAK5dPwKeIf8s/edit?usp=sharing
The data segregation sheet was a totally unnecessary step I took that is not utilized. I'm just leaving it there in case I do think of a way to use it in that format.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I had that turned on the copy. Please try again when convenient.

Comment: B59 needs to be: `="contains '"&TEXTJOIN("' or Col3 contains '", 1, $O$41:$O$57)&"'"` and then Y3 can be `=QUERY({'Transaction Dump'!$A7:$J}, "select Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col9 where Col3 "&C59, 0)` - answer updated...

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly!

I'm a little confused over the syntax for my own understanding though. So at the end of whats in Y3 `where Col3 "&C59, 0)`  Doesn't `&C59` have to be within the `"` to be considered part of the statement? Also, what was the purpose of changing the Query from a normal range to one closed in `{ }`? I thought those were only for multiple query ranges.

Comment: nope, only if its part of the formula only then it needs to be enclosed with double quotes. one outside as cell reference it needs to be without double quotes. as for the array brackets `{}` its a choice preference... the upside is that when you move it or add columns before it will work coz of `Col` references. if you would have a letter  reference you would need to edit your formula to match actual columns after adding/removing columns or moving formula around the sheet

Comment: EDIT, thank you for all your help. I had another question, but the solution was just adding a space in the end. Here's the completed formula, restricting for both date ranges and the filtered view.
`=QUERY({'Transaction Dump'!$A7:$J}, "select Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col9 where " & "Col2 >= date '" & text(E3,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and Col2 <= date'" & text(K3,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and Col3 " &C59, 0)`

Comment: There still exists a problem, but i'll be a while before I can correct it. I'm realizing that it considers either my date range and the first filter, or only the filtered items after the first.